# JQuery "undo" an action by calling another function when back clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Is there a way to "undo" a function executed by jQuery when the back button is clicked? For example, my function that I want to execute is named doSomething:

```
function doSomething(button) {
     ...clicking the button does something...
}
```

And I have an undo function that undoes the above function, undoDoSomething:

```
function undoDoSomething(button) {
    ....undoes the doSomething function...
}
```

How do I call the function for the button and then if the back button is clicked right after I execute the function, I can call the undoDoSomething function to undo that function?

I know jQuery History goes back to a previous page saved in history but how do I use that to call a function?

Comment: Use the popstate event, coupled with the history.pushstate. when a change is made, push it onto history, then when the backbutton is pressed causing a popstate, you can catch that, see the url and associated data, and perform an action. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the history api makes this easy: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9dRY/

html:

```
<button>Increase</button>click back button to decrease
<span id="counter">0</span>
```

js:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var count = +$("#counter").text() + 1;
    history.pushState({count:count});
    $(counter).text(count);
})
$(window).on("popstate",function(e){
    if (e.originalEvent.state)
        $(counter).text(e.originalEvent.state.count);    
})
```

On each action, add to the history, and then each back button click will undo each change (of course, you have to develop the undo part. In this case, i just stored what the count should be changed to at that point and changed it.)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Take note of the browser support, this code will work in all modern browsers and IE10+. oldIE will need a workaround either using an iframe or a hash in the url.

Here's the same example with an added decrease button to show that it doesn't really change anything: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9dRY/1/ it even inherantly supports the forward button(redo).

Update: fixed losing initial state: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9dRY/2/

Comment: No problem. i enjoy getting a chance to use this api. Since it doesn't support IE8 i'm very limited to where i can use it without adding a lot of complexity due to adding an IE8 polyfill.

Comment: Now I have a strange error which I would be glad to get some advice on. When you push a state, that state does not become immediately available when you pop out the previous state when clicking the back button. For example, in your example code, you pushed "2" when you increase. But when the back button is clicked, the "1" state is popped out. Unfortunately, I need the state that I just pushed "2" but I haven't figured out how to get it. Advice greatly appreciated!

Comment: i'm confused. When you press increase, pushstate is used, storing the value `1`. When you press back, popstate happens going back to the original value where you should set it back to default ( i didn't do that in my demo, so yes there's a bug there.) is that what you are referring it?

Answer (score 0):

You could call your undo function on the window.unload event

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    undoDoSomething();
};
```

Comment: I only want to execute undoDoSomething() only if I have executed doSomething the moment before. I believe this will call that function regardless of whether or not I call doSomething().

Comment: I see. Seems to me like you would need to add some logic into `undoDoSometing()` to check and see if `doSomething()` has been called.

Answer (score 0):

You can usue `beforeunload` that is executed when leaving the page

```
var called = false;

function doSomething(button) {
     called = true;
}


$(window).on('beforeunload',function(e){
    if(called){
        //call your function here
        undoDoSomething()
    }

});
```

Comment: I only want to execute undoDoSomething() only if I have executed doSomething the moment before. I believe this will call that function regardless of whether or not I call doSomething().

Comment: You can use a global boolean variable set to false and set it to true inside your dosomething function then check in the beforunload function if the booleans is true then you call your undosomething function

Comment: Sorry, your answer has been helpful so far, but in the case that other functions are called after doSomething, it wouldn't necessarily make sense to add "called = false" to every other function that I ever call. I want the back button to function like an actual back button meaning it only calls undoDoSomething only if doSomething is the action that is called immediately before.